# Ubuntu v18 installation fails in Virtual Box 6 and 6.1

Tags: server, virtualbox

Team:

Ubuntu v18fails to install in both Virtualbox 6 and 6.1 and I see a few errors in VBox and VBox hardening log files.

I am using Win10 O.S

```
00:00:32.661259 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_VM_ERROR (0x80bb0003) aIID={4680b2de-8690-11e9-b83d-5719e53cf1de} aComponent={DisplayWrap} aText={Could not take a screenshot (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=-37


4828.538: supHardNtVpGetImport: Failed to find symbol 0xffffffff / 'NtUserRegisterClassExWOW' in 'win32u.dll': Unknown Status -610 (0xfffffd9e)
4828.538: Error (rc=-5629):
4828.538: RTLdrGetBits failed on image user32.dll: Unknown Status -610 (0xfffffd9e)
4828.538: supR3HardenedWinInit: SUPHARDNTVPKIND_SELF_PURIFICATION_LIMITED -> Unknown Status -5629 (0xffffea03), cFixes=2
4828.538: '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe' has no imports
4828.538: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 24202 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe)

2c60.4644: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: error opening 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\wintab32.dll': 0 (NtPath=\??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\wintab32.dll; Input=C:\WINDOWS\system32\wintab32.dll; rcNtGetDll=0x0

2c60.47c0: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> -5667 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Users\rsolomon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\20.134.0705.0008\amd64\FileSyncShell64.dll)
2c60.47c0: Error (rc=0):
2c60.47c0: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: rc=Unknown Status -5667 (0xffffe9dd) fImage=1 fProtect=0x0 fAccess=0x0 \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Users\rsolomon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\20.134.0705.0008\amd64\FileSyncShell64.dll: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: TrustedInstaller is not the owner of '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Users\rsolomon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\20.134.0705.0008\amd64\FileSyncShell64.dll'.
2c60.47c0: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Users\rsolomon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\20.134.0705.0008\amd64\FileSyncShell64.dll
2c60.47c0: Error (rc=0):
2c60.47c0: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile: CryptCATAdminEnumCatalogFromHash failed ERROR_NOT_FOUND (1168)
```

I am unable to find an option to attach the log-files for reference. Can you please help me find a fix for this. I searched for the fixes but am unable to land a hit on these errors.
Note:
I did a complete unistall and re-installed Virtual Box and even downloaded the latest Ubuntu Server.

Comment: The 'latest' Ubuntu Server is 20.04, not 18.04 (and not "v18"), so it's not clear which release of Ubuntu you are trying to install. I've installed both VirtualBox 6 and 6.1. It works.

Comment: I'm seeing a Windows permission error of some kind in your output: `TrustedInstaller is not the owner of '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Users\rsolomon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\20.134.0705.0008\amd64\FileSyncShell64.dll'` Looks like you might be trying to install to a remote or virtual drive (Advice: Don't). That's not an Ubuntu-related issue.

Comment: FYI:   Ubuntu Core 18 is a for IoT devices and appliances. All Ubuntu server & desktop releases use the *yy.mm* (*year.month* of release) format as they have multiple releases per year. Only specialist releases use *yy* format, so check what you are actually trying to install.

Comment: I meant 18.04 version. I dont have 20.04 at the moment so trying with version 18. Tried unchecking some options uder turn off windows features. Lemme confirm if it works

Comment: I unchecked Container and Hyper-V (Earlier my VMs worked even when Hyper-V was checked) and reinstalled Virtual Box 6.1 again. Used Ubuntu 18.04 and its working